# Attach resource policy to HttpApi in CDK (alpha)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I'm targeting an API Gateway endpoint from AWS EventBridge. Documentation says I should add a [resource policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-use-resource-based.html#eb-api-gateway-permissions) to the API endpoint. But as I'm using the new ApiGatewayV2, there doesn't seem to be anything that would allow adding a resource policy to a `HttpApi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api Gateway v2 [does not support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html#http-api-vs-rest.differences.authorization) resource policy authorization.

It is a general constraint, not one imposed by the CDK.